# Can Blu Ray Videos be Played on a Computer that Has no Blu Ray Player?

Tags: blu-ray

Can a blu ray disk image be virtually mounted to play a blue ray movie (like ISO images can)?

If so then using what software?

I just want to know for sure before I delicate my slow connection to downloading a huge blu ray file.

Comment: I don't see what the upvotes are for. This is common sense.

Comment: @chipperyman573 Why did you downvote ? What answer do you think would be common sense ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Blu Ray image file on your hard disk then tools like [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite) can mount it.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the Blu-Ray image, you can indeed mount it like Sathya suggested with [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite). However, it's worth checking if your PC has HD-Graphics capability. If it doesn't, the Blu-Ray image will not play properly. If that is so, you should download the DVD-image instead of the Blu-Ray, it is playable on your PC AND it would save you about 10-15 GBs of download on your "delicate slow connection".

Answer (score 0):

You actually have many options here.
A Blu-ray ISO file can be played a number of different ways. You don't even always have to mount it. Depends on how you play it.
For PC's you just need a software media player that supports Blu-ray Disc Java (BD-J). Examples of such players are:

- ArcSoft TotalMedia Theatre
- [Corel WinDVD](https://www.windvdpro.com/en/)
- [Cyberlink PowerDVD](https://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdvd-ultra/features_en_EU.html) <--------- recommended
- [DVDFab Player](https://www.dvdfab.cn/media-player.htm)
- [Kodi](http://www.kodi.tv) (from v18 - not out yet)
- Nero Blu-ray Player
- [VideoLAN VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

Note that you will also need to have [Java](https://www.java.com/en/) installed, in a bit version that matches the bit version of the software media player you choose. E.g. 32bit VLC => 32bit Java. (The way to get a certain bit version of Java, is to visit www.java.com with a browser in that bit-version. E.g. visit with a 64bit browser if you wish to get 64bit Java (because you've downloaded a 64bit software media player)).

Java is needed to run the menus on most Blu-rays.

All of the above players are available for Windows. If you're a Linux user, your options are currently limited to Kodi v18 and VLC 3.0.1. If you're a Mac user, check out [MacGo Blu-ray Player](https://www.macblurayplayer.com/).

A Blu-ray ISO can also be played on a ton of different hardware media centers and TV-boxes from harddisk or USB. Examples:

- Newer Egreat (and other Android) devices (A5 / A10 / A11 / A1080 / S5A)
- VidOn.me devices
- Dune HD devices (Base 3.0, Duo, MAX, Prime 3.0, Pro, Smart B1/D1/H1, Solo)
- Popcorn Hour devices (A-200, A-210, A-300, C-200, C-300)
- And more (HDX BD1, Netgear NeoTV 550, Pioneer BDP-62FD, QNAP NMP-1000P)